# Show button on hover of parent and hide it on hover of sibling using only CSS

Tags: html, css, hover

I apologize in advance if this might be a re-post, I searched a bit for showing div on `:hover` of parent.

None of them helped me.

However I have bit different scenario.
If there is any other question with same scenario please share the link of the same.

What I want is to show a button on `:hover` of `.image-wrapper` and hide it on `:hover` of its `share` text.

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ACgtp) is the code what I have done so far.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139423/hovering-a-div-but-not-hovering-a-div-which-is-outside-the-main-div-because-of) is the js solution, but I am looking for CSS solution.

**It should be working on IE8 too.** So `+` selector will also not work. Is is possible using only CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done only with CSS.

What you need to do is get both the siblings in one `div` (e.g `.innerWrap`) and hide the button on `hover` of `.innerWrap`.

[Here is the demo for it.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fbsAq)